# I need help sorting specific numbers inside an array of strings to descend

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I have an array of strings that i need to sort those strings based on the first 4 numbers in each string. But how do I target those numbers in order to sort? The code works just fine I just need to sort it.

Ive tried .substring but I don't think its the right method for this.

```
var volunteers = [ '9.05', '16.29', '26.67', '0.00', '2.25' ]

getResults: function(volunteers) {
  this.results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < volunteers.length; i++) {
    var dayNames = this.data[i][3] || " ";
    var result = (volunteers[i] + " additional volunteers are needed on day " + i +" " +dayNames);
    this.results.push(result);        
  }


console.log(this.results)
  return this.results;

}
//Expected
[ '26.67 additional volunteers are needed on day 2 Tuesday',
'16.29 additional volunteers are needed on day 1 Monday',
'9.05 additional volunteers are needed on day 0 Sunday',
'2.25 additional volunteers are needed on day 4 ',
'0.00 additional volunteers are needed on day 3 Wednesday' ]

//Actual
 [ '9.05 additional volunteers are needed on day 0 Sunday',
 '16.29 additional volunteers are needed on day 1 Monday',
 '26.67 additional volunteers are needed on day 2 Tuesday',
 '0.00 additional volunteers are needed on day 3 Wednesday',
 '2.25 additional volunteers are needed on day 4  ' ]
```

Comment: please add the array unsorted and the sorted version.

Comment: Sorry, I did but didn't format it correctly for code

Comment: Why can't you just take the volunteers array as numbers instead of string and make sorting easier. Sort the array first and then build the sentences

Comment: well the numbers come from a different function which calculates them and stores them into an array of strings

Comment: You can map sorted version of `volunteers` with dates using `indexOf` of the original `volunteers`

Comment: try storing volunteers and corresponding day into 'map' as key and value and then apply any sorting algorithm on your key and then print as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var volunteers = [ '9.05', '16.29', '26.67', '0.00', '2.25' ];

var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

this.results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < volunteers.length; i++) {
  var result = {
    'value':volunteers[i] , 
    'name' : volunteers[i] + " additional volunteers are needed on day " + i +" " +days[i]
  }
  this.results.push(result);
}

this.results.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.value - b.value;
}).reverse();

var result = this.results.map(a => a.name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort them first:

```
getResults: function(volunteers) {
  volunteers = volunteers.sort((a, b) => +a - +b);
  // Use sorted `volunteers` 
}
```

Comment: That'll just sort the numbers, while that is part of what I need, those numbers need to keep their respective dates in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the indices and sort them with the values descending and map the strings with the sorted indices.

```js
var volunteers = ['9.05', '16.29', '26.67', '0.00', '2.25'],
    days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    result = [...volunteers.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => volunteers[b] - volunteers[a])
        .map(i => `${volunteers[i]} additional volunteers are needed on day ${i} ${days[i]}`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getNumber(string) {
  const numbers = string.match(/[0-9\.]+/g)[0] || 0
  return Number(numbers);
}
function sort (volunteers) {
  return volunteers.sort((a, b) => getNumber(a) - getNumber(b));
}
sort(volunteers)
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat` can be used to get the numeric part :

```js
var arr = [ '9.05 additional volunteers are needed on day 0 Sunday',
           '16.29 additional volunteers are needed on day 1 Monday',
           '26.67 additional volunteers are needed on day 2 Tuesday',
            '0.00 additional volunteers are needed on day 3 Wednesday',
           '2.25 additional volunteers are needed on day 4' ]

console.log( arr.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b) - parseFloat(a)) )
```